# querySelectorAll not working for textarea?

Tags: angular

When i do like this:

```
let txtarea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
console.log('aaa',txtarea);
```

I get empty array, and for input i get result.Any suggestion how can i select all textarea? I tried with class but same problem, empty array.  This is my function:

```
 autogrow(){

        let txtarea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

        console.log('aaa',txtarea);
        [].forEach.call(txtarea, function(txtarea) {
        txtarea.style.height = (txtarea.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
        });
    }
```

Comment: where do you call that function?

Comment: problem is with ngIf that querySelectors not see elements

Comment: create a plunker or show full code